# Unable to check if file exists or not in web project

Tags: java, jsp

I have a pdf file in my web project at the below location :

"static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf "

"static" is present in the WebContent. The context root of the project is "pas".

In one of the jsp, I need to check if the file Home_insurance_booklet.pdf exists or not.  I tried in many ways but unable to succeed. Below is the code I have used.

```
String filePath = request.getContextPath()+"/static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf";
if(new File(filePath.toString()).exists()) {
------
}
```

Through the file exists, the condition is returning false. How to check if the file exists or not w.r.t to certain location in the root of the web project ?

Edit:
File path displayed is
/pas/static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf

Comment: if you print filePath what do you get?

Comment: @jamp  I am getting : /pas/static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf

Comment: I guess that path does not actually exist, does it? bare in mind it starts with /, thus it is an absolute path... maybe you want to check pas/static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf

Comment: try with absolute path or canonical path

Comment: I just re-read your question, actually you may wanna check just "static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf"... I would have to have a clearer idea of the structure of your project to tell you which one...

Comment: @jamp let me check with your latest suggestion

Comment: @jamp "static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf"  is working  when I have used  "getServletContext().getRealPath".  Stefan has mentioned it. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf")
File file = new File(path)
if (file.exists()) {
  // Success
}
```

And here is the API-Doc of `getRealPath()`:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
StringBuilder finalPathToFile = new StringBuilder(context.getRealPath("/"));
```

The **ServletContext#getRealPath()** converts a web content path (the path in the expanded WAR folder structure on the server's disk file system) to an absolute disk file system path.

The `"/"` represents the web content root.

After that append in this way :

```
finalPathToFile.append("/static/Downloadables/20/Home_insurance_booklet.pdf");
```

Then use

```
if(new File(finalPathToFile.toString()).exists()) {
---------------------
doWhateverYouWantToDo
---------------------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether file is loaded in the project or not. and then try for absolute path first of the file in your code then try for relative path.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a file system based URL instead of relative web based URL.